# Rviz: Is it possible to overlay images on top of the camera's image?

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Lets say my camera is subscribed to a topic that produces raw images and display through rviz's camera, I want to have a second node produce some images and then overlay on top of the camera's images then display.

Is this possible in ROS? I'm new to ROS too. Any answers will be very much appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286764/rviz:-is-it-possible-to-overlay-images-on-top-of-the-camera%27s-image?/) by [henrytan97](https://answers.ros.org/users/34340/henrytan97/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-03-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-27**:
What is "rviz's camera" exactly? Are you referring to the `Camera` display, the `Image` display, or something else?

**Comment by [henrytan97](https://answers.ros.org/users/34340/henrytan97/) on 2018-03-27**:
I'm referring to the Camera display. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not aware of any way to make the `Camera` display do what you want. It only takes in a single `Image` topic (together with a `CameraInfo` one).

You could perhaps place the images produced by the "second node" somewhere in RViz's 3D scene (and in the viewport of the `Camera` display). See #q227304 for a plugin that can do that.

Alternatively, you could perhaps merge / overlay / blend the image(s) (streams) first, publish the result and then subscribe the `Camera` display to that.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [henrytan97](https://answers.ros.org/users/34340/henrytan97/) on 2018-03-27**:
Cool, thank you very much for that.